# getting not resolve host while calling https IP through webclient

Tags: java, vert.x

I am using vert.x webclient libraryto call HTTP API but getting Something went wrong failed to resolve XXXX  I have also given ssl(true) option .Below are the details

```
WebClient
      .post(443, "https://XX.XXX.XX.XXX", "/postData")
      .ssl(true)
    .sendJsonObject(
       new JsonObject().put("data", data).put("signature", URLEncoder.encode(data,"UTF-8")).put("version", "2"),ar -> {
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of the `post` method should be an IP address or hostname. It shouldn't be prefixed with `https://`. This should work:

```
WebClient
  .post(443, "XX.XXX.XX.XXX", "/postData")
  .ssl(true)
  .sendJsonObject(json, ar -> {
    // Handle async result
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But removing https, its throwing " Failed to create SSL connection"

Comment: can you check please?

Comment: @munna without a full stack trace it's difficult to answer. please share on the vert.x user forum. but i think your question is answered anyway